# Animate two DIV's side by side with jQuery, without pushing the other to the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

So I'm trying to get one DIV to slide off-screen to the left, and then a preloaded DIV (offscreen) to slide in from the right.
This pretty much works, except for one thing: 
It Pushes the old DIV to the bottom when it animates..

But they need to stay next to each other, as if your flipping through pages..

You'll understand when you check this: http://gasmar.home.xs4all.nl/flits/index.html
First click on 'agenda' and then on 'zakelijk', you'll notice the DIV that should be pushed left should nicely animate like the incoming DIV, but it gets pushed to the bottom of the new DIV.. after that is takes the right position, but that's just not right.

Here's my code:

```
//Preload DIV outside page:
$(document).ready(function() {

//preLoad 2 HTMLS:
preLoad("agendaPage", "agenda.html");
preLoad("zakelijkPage", "zakelijk.html");

//preLoad Function
function preLoad(page, file){
  $('#preloadDIV').after('<DIV id="'+ page+ '">'+page+'</DIV>');

    $('#'+ page +'').css(
    {
     //Load page DIV and hide it 1000px to the right
     'marginLeft' : "1000px",

    }).load(''+file+' #'+page+'DIV').hide();

  };
});



//Bind ClickEvent
$('#zakelijk').bind('click', function(){
    clickButton("zakelijk");
});

//Button function
function clickButton(name) 
{
    fadeCurrentPageLeft(name);
   //Load Page
    renderPage(name);
};

//Fade in new DIV
function renderPage(name)
{
   $('#' + name).unbind('click');
   $('#'+name+'Page')
   .attr("id", 'currentPage')
   .animate(
    {
      'marginLeft' : "-=1000px",
      'position' : "absolute",
    }, 
    {duration: 800, queue: false }, 'linear')
    .show();

    //Set ID to current Page
    $('#'+name+'Page');

};

//Fade out old DIV
function fadeCurrentPageLeft(name) 
{
   $('#currentPage')
   .animate(
{
   'marginLeft' : "-=1000px",
}, 
    {duration: 3000, queue: false }, 'linear')
   .hide("drop", {}, {duration: 3000, queue: false })
   .attr("id", name+'Page');
};
```

I tried doing it with relative coordinates, but they just keep pushing each other away, even when the z-position is different for each DIV it doesnt work..

Maybe I should preload the DIV's differently? but I dont know in what other way...

(Also, as a follow up, I'd like the DIV's to stay the size they end up as (not all strechty like now) , although I have most parameters in % so when you resize the windows it wil stay nice and proportioned)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I did not update your current code, but you can use it as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtUz6/3/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">SLIDE!!!</a>
<div id="container">
    <div id="page1">

    </div>
    <div id="page2">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 400px; 
    position: relative;

}
#page1
{
     position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: green;
}
#page2
{
     position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#container").height($("#page1").height())
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#page1").animate({left: -400}, 500); 
        $("#page2").show().css("left", 400).animate({left: 0}, 500); 
        $("#container").animate({ height : $("#page2").height()}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will test it soon, is it the "overflow: hidden" that fixes it? or the .show?

Comment: It is the position absolute, I don't know if your floating the DIV's you want to move, if you do, the content of the pages width is not 2x the page you wan't to show, and if it does not fit, it will be placed below the other element. With position absolute, you can move it outside the page and on eachother.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED (had made some other tries and had pasted the wrong version. Now the right one is here).

Basically, the trick is very simple:

On the page overlaying the previous one, put in the style of it, z-index:+1 and, when animation finished, change it back with z-index:-1. This last feat can be achieved in the callBack: (...).animate( { .... },..., function () { (...).css( { 'z-index':'-1' } ) } );

I played around with the hope that I could achieve it without using the plug-in you are using (jQuery-UI). This is what I got:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function paginate(from,to,url,styling) {
        loadPage(to,url,styling);
        $('#'+from).css( { 'top':'0px','left':'0px' } );
        $('#'+to).css( { 'top':'0px', 'left':'501px' } ).show();
        if ($('#'+from).height() > $('#'+to).height()) {
            var blankArea = $('#'+from).height() - $('#'+to).height();
            $('#'+to).css( { 'height':$('#'+to).height()+blankArea } );
            $("<div style='position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; height:"+blankArea+"px; background-color:white; ' ></div>").appendTo($('#'+to));
        }
        $('#'+to).animate( { 'zIndex':'+1','left':'0px' },3000, function () {
            $('#'+from).hide();
            $('#'+from).unbind('click');
            $('#'+from).remove();
            $('#'+to).css( { 'zIndex':'-1' } );

            // to exemplify a forever cicle:
            if (from == 'zekelijkPage')
                styling = 'float:left; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background-color:green; width:500px; height:500px; display:none;'
            else styling = 'float:left; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background-color:red; width:500px; height:650px; display:none;'
            $('#'+to).bind('click', function(){
                paginate(to,from,'',styling);
            });
        });
    }

    function loadPage(pageName,url,styling) {
        $('#wrapper').append("<div id='" + pageName + "' style='" + styling + " ' ></div>");
        if (url != '') {
            $.get(url, function(data) { //url returns escaped html
                $('#'+pageName).html(data);
            });
        } else $('#'+pageName).html('<p>blah blah blah</p><p></p><p>CLICK THIS PAGE</p><p></p><p></p><p>Page name: '+pageName+'</p>');
        // or
        //if (url != '') //load html into div
        //  $('#'+pageName).load(url);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //preLoad 2 HTMLS:
        //$('#agendaPage').load('agenda.html');
        //$('#zekelijkPage').load('zakelijk.html');
        loadPage('zekelijkPage','','float:left; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background-color:green; width:500px; height:500px;');
        $('#zekelijkPage').bind('click', function(){
            paginate('zekelijkPage','agendaPage','','float:left; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background-color:red; width:500px; height:650px; display:none;');
        });
    });

</script>



<body style='position:relative; width:100%; margin:20px auto; 
 background: transparent; ' >

   <div id='wrapper' style='position:relative; margin:0 auto; width:100%; ' >
   </div>
</body>
```

Example here: http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/paginate.html